# Is it possible to use std::accumulate with std::min?

Tags: c++, stl, accumulate

I am trying to combine `std::accumulate` with `std::min`.  Something like this (won't compile):

```
vector<int> V{2,1,3};   
cout << accumulate(V.begin()+1, V.end(), V.front(), std::min<int>);
```

Is it possible?
Is it possible to do without writing wrapper functor for `std::min`?
I know that I can do this with lambdas:

```
vector<int> V{2,1,3};   
cout << std::accumulate(
    V.begin()+1, V.end(),
    V.front(), 
    [](int a,int b){ return min(a,b);}
);
```

And I know there is `std::min_element`.  I am not trying to find min element, I need to combine `std::accumulate` with `std::min` (or `::min`) for my library which allows function-programming like expressions in C++.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that there are [several overloads of the `min` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min):

```
template <class T> const T& min(const T& a, const T& b);

template <class T, class BinaryPredicate>
const T& min(const T& a, const T& b, BinaryPredicate comp);
```

Therefore, your code is ambiguous, the compiler does not know which overload to choose. You can state which one you want by using an intermediate function pointer:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> V{2,1,3};
  int const & (*min) (int const &, int const &) = std::min<int>;
  std::cout << std::accumulate(V.begin() + 1, V.end(), V.front(), min);
}
```

Comment: You could use an ugly cast too `(const int& (*)(const int&, const int&))std::min<int>`.

Comment: I tend to like the lambda version better.

Comment: @JesseGood: y u no `static_cast`? :\

Comment: @Mehrdad: I thought it would make it too long, but now that I think about it, it does help readability.

Comment: Does anyone know why this doesn't seem to be a problem for C++98 compiles, including `-std=gnu++98` for GCC where `-std=gnu++11` errors out?  (Of course, you have to remove the new-style initialization of `V`).

Comment: If you use a cast, I would suggest using a `typedef` for readability, at least: `typedef const int& (*min_func)(const int&, const int&);` or `using min_func = const int& (*)(const int&, const int&);` then you can use `std::accumulate(..., static_cast<min_func>(std::min<int>));`. I wonder if `std::function` would also work? `std::function<const int&(const int&, const int&)> min_func = std::min<int>; std::accumulate(..., min_func);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure, `std::function` would work. It would incur the cost of creating a `std::function` along with the type erasure it performs though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is unspecified (possibly ill-formed) behaviour, as you [can't take the address of most functions in `std`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/namespace.std#6)

Answer (score 0):

From C++20 you can use std::**ranges**::min

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <climits>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,47,5};
    std::cout << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), INT_MAX, std::ranges::min) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), INT_MIN, std::ranges::max) << std::endl; 
}
```

> 1
> 47

Note that there is no `std::ranges::accumulate`, as it was not done for C++20.