# Pairwise comparison of std::vector elements using C++11 lambdas

Tags: c++11

I'm kind of having fun with C++11 and trying to come up with a more elegant way of taking a pairwise comparison of two `std::vector<double>`. For pairwise maximum, I am using the rather inelegant

```
typedef std::vector<double> vec;
vec pairwiseMax(vec& a, vec& b)
{
    ASSERT(a.size() == b.size());
    vec c(a); // seed with a
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if (b[i] > a[i]) // bigger than
            c[i] = b[i];
    }
    return c;
}
```

However, using lambdas and `std::for_each` would seem better, as in the following which extracts the absolute maximum of a `std::vector<double>` but I'm not coming up with anything.

```
inline double vecabs(vec v)
{
    if (v.empty()) return 0.0;
    vec::iterator it = 
        std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), 
        // Start lambda function
        [](double const& a, double const& b)
        {
            return (std::abs(a) < std::abs(b));
        });
    return *it;
};
```

---

After Igor's post, I now have:

```
vec c;
c.reserve(a.size());
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
    std::back_inserter(c),
    [](double const& d, double const& e)
    { return max(d, e); });
```

Two questions:

1. Why not just copy `vec a` into `vec c` like I had before?
2. Isn't using the back_inserter adding a lot of additional operations? If `c==a` to start with, then fewer inserts to `c` would be required.

Like this:

```
vec c(a); // seed with a
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
    c.begin(),
    [](double const& d, double const& e)
    { return max(d, e); });
return c;
```

Comment: Igor's method is more efficient then your original method. If a and b contain uniformly distributed random values, your original method will make 1.5N copies but Igor's method only makes 1N copies.

Answer (score 3):

```
vec c;
c.reserve(a.size());
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
               std::back_inserter(c),
               std::max<double>);
```

Comment: You may want to add a `c.reserve(a.size())`

Comment: @igor - Hadn't found `std::transform` - thanks! Your suggestion doesn't work though because `std::max<double>` has multiple overloads (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626304/is-it-possible-to-use-stdaccumulate-with-stdmin).

Comment: This can be made to work if we use an anonymous function. See my response.

Answer (score 1):

Igor's solution is great, but I had trouble compiling it. I found I needed to wrap std::max in an anonymous function to get it to compile.

Here are two template functions which allow taking the pairwise maximum for an arbitrary number of vectors:

```
// pairwise maximum                                               
template<typename T>                                              
vector<T> pmax(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b) {
    std::vector<T> c;                                             
    assert(a.size() == b.size());                                 
    c.reserve(a.size());                                          
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),                 
                   std::back_inserter(c),                         
                   [](T a, T b) { return std::max<T>(a, b); });   
    return c;                                                     
}                                                                 

// maximum of all vectors
template<typename T>                                                      
vector<T> vpmax(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& vv) {                  
    std::vector<T> c;                                                     
    if (vv.empty()) return c;                                             
    c = vv.front();                                                       
    typename std::vector<std::vector<T> >::const_iterator v = vv.begin(); 
    ++v; // skip the first element                                        
    for ( ; v != vv.end(); ++v) {                                         
        c = pmax(c, *v);                                                  
    }                                                                     
    return c;                                                             
}
```

Comment: You may already have a max defined (e.g. Visual Studio). If so just write "(std::max)" instead of "std::max" to get the preprocessor to recognize it as a single entity. No need for an extra function.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I can try that out.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on gcc. I'll leave it as is.